# com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to

Tags: java, casting, rmi

GameV1 game;

```
  public void connect() {
    connect("//localhost/Game");
    if (getServer() != null) {
        game= (GameV1) getServer();

    }

}
```

this method "connect("//localhost/Game");" just sets the server on the upperclase which then is casted to GameV1
Game=interface
GameV1=concrete class with implements Game

if (getServer() != null) 
this returns true but i get this error when cast
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to GameV1

Comment: the error is pretty indicative. You're casting between two incompatible types. Look at the hierarchy of your GameV1 object; does it implement the right interfaces?

Answer (score 7):

With a RMI remote object you can't cast to the concrete class. You have to cast to the remote interface.

Comment: When do i cast to concrete?
when i recieve the object in the client?

Comment: If you are sending an actual object to the client, then you can cast to its type in the client, yes. But if you are just sending a remote reference to the client, then no.

Comment: You don't *what* the method calls? There's a missing word in your comment.

Comment: I casted to interface now but i still get exception
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to servidor.Game

Game contains all the classes in the server, not all the classes are named as remote or serializable could that be the source of the problem???

Comment: Which exception? Which interface? Have you read some RMI tutorial to check what you are supposed to be doing? Maybe you should try to get a really simple example RMI program working first, then try to do something more advanced.

Comment: The remote interface class is supposed to contain all the methods that you want to call remotely. What you describe here doesn't make much sense.